How to get unique count of values within a specific date range avoiding duplicate values, for a specific location
I am attempting to obtain the sum of a column that has duplicate values, and have those duplicate values counted as 1 instance within a specific date range, that is representing the reporting week. So this count should show the count of unique values (kioskID) within that week beginning range.
I have the populate sheet with in E13 I need the count of the kioskID within the date range shown in E9. This count should exclude the duplicate counts.
I have tried countifs, sumifs, frequency and the return value is always 0 when that is not correct. I have tried to pivot the out but I want to avoid using a pivot table reducing manual input to the row in sheet 1.
Example of desired outcome: In week 14 (based on dates in raw data, and the state in source column) count unique values from Raw data Column A, but do not count duplicate values.



Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell F2
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$38,
       ($C$2:$C$38>=F1)*
       ($C$2:$C$38<=F1+6)*
       ($D$2:$D$38="WA"),0))<>0))


Or, Using BYCOL()
=BYCOL(F1:M1,LAMBDA(α, 
  SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A38,
  (C2:C38>=α)*
  (C2:C38<=α+6)*
  (D2:D38="WA"),0))<>0))))


One another alternative using COUNTIFS()
=SUM(--(COUNTIFS($A:$A,UNIQUE($A:$A),$C:$C,">="&F1,$C:$C,"<="&F1+6,$D:$D,"WA")>0))


You just need to add the Location criteria in the FILTER() function.

Is it possible instead of "WA" to have that be a cell reference like B12 for example?

@PeterDelSol yes ofcourse just change this ="WA" to this =B12 for example i have shown using WA or in the last one change "WA" to B12

Awesome Thank you!

@PeterDelSol thank you very much !
